# Mithril: defer route configuration until DOM is ready

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

My app has div in its view, which will be used as mounting point for pages of my app.

```
app.view = function(ctrl) {
    return [
        appHeader.view(),
        appNav.view(),
        m("#page")
    ];
};
```

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
m.mount(document.getElementById("app"), app);

m.route.mode = "hash";
m.route(document.getElementById("page"), "", {
    "select_company": admin.SelectCompany
});
```

It works if I include `<div id="page"></div>` directly in app.html.
How to solve the above issue, without writing html directly?

Answer (score 3):

I was told by @ArthurClemens and @barneycarroll through Gitter chat that using m.mount() and m.route() both in one application is not recommended approach. One solution provided by @barneycarroll is to only use m.route(), and use a function that will return page view along with other common parts of the application like below (jsbin is [here](http://jsbin.com/koqomo/2/edit?html,js,output)):

```
var header = {
  view : function(){
    return m( "h1", "This is the persistent site header" )
  }
}

var nav = {
  controller : function(){
    this.links = [
      [ "/", "Home" ],
      [ "/select_company", "Companies" ]
    ]
  },
  view : function( ctrl ){
    return m( "ul", 
      ctrl.links.map( function( link ){
    return m( "li", 
      m( "a", {
        config : m.route,
        href   : link[ 0 ]
      }, link[ 1 ] )
    )
      } )
    )
  }
}

function furnish( component ){
  return {
    view : function(){
      return [
    header,
    nav,
    component
      ]
    }
  }
}

var home = {
  view : function(){
    return m( "h2", "Welcome!" )
  }
}

var selectCompany = {
  view : function(){
    return m( "h2", "Please select a company" )
  }
}

m.route.mode = "hash";
m.route( document.body, "/", {
    "/"              : furnish( home ),
    "/select_company": furnish( selectCompany )
} );
```